# Project Web Access, Resources from Databases

Tags: project-server, project-web-access

Is there a way to retrieve the resources (names) of a current project? Here at my work we work with the Scrum methodology, so in each sprint we create a new project file.

Each project file is synced with PWA (Project Server Web Access). I have permission on the database to retrieve information.

Is there a way to pull resources names from the database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can, but it depends on the version of Project Server you are using.

**Project Server 2007**

This version introduced the reporting database. It is populated whenever a project is published. (You can query unpublished data by using the drafts database.)

Microsoft have provided a [report pack](http://blogs.msdn.com/chrisfie/archive/2009/08/21/project-server-2007-report-pack-ii-an-incredible-asset-you-should-all-leverage.aspx) which may already contain the report you need. It also contains many examples on how to use the reporting database.

The complete database schema is available for download in the [Project 2007 SDK](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms512767.aspx) (look for pj12ReportingDB.chm).

**Project Server 2003**

As this is an older version there is less information available, however there are example queries from [EPM Central](http://www.epmcentral.com/pjadmin/dbscripts-msps3.php) that show how to query resources.

The complete database schema is also [available from Microsoft](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=AC5CC775-1367-4B66-870D-F280C054EFE2).

Comment: I did access to the reporting database in Project 2007... by the way you always answer my questions lol! thanks!